# Safari on Windows cannot open aspx page

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, safari

I have a aspx login page that opens fine on `localhost`. However the same page doesn't open when on the internet, I am using Safari browser on Windows and getting below message:

```
Safari can't open the page. The error is: "" (kCFErrorDomainWinSock:10054)
```

Any hints as to where to look for the problem?

Comment: Can you open it with other browsers?

Comment: Yes it opens fine in all other major browsers